# How to append additional data via the toObject method?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50922023/9950391), and the user has appended something to the toObject method here:

```
PostModel changedModel = documentChange.getDocument().toObject(PostModel.class).withDocId(docID);
```

Where and how do I define the `withDocId` so that I can pass the docId? Is it in the POJO class?

My POJO class has this method:

```
public void withDocId(String docId) {
        this.docId = docId;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line of code:

```
documentChange.getDocument().toObject(PostModel.class)
```

Returns an object of type `PostModel`. When calling `.withDocId(docID)` on that object, it means that `withDocId` method is a method within that class.

> Is it in the POJO class?

Yes it is.

**Edit:**

> how do I define it in the POJO class?

You can define a method in your POJO class in the same way you define the setters and getters. So it might be something line this:

```
public void withDocId(String docID) {
    //Your logic
}
```

**Edit2:**

In order to make this line of code compile:

```
PostModel changedModel = documentChange.getDocument().toObject(PostModel.class).withDocId(docID);
```

The `.withDocId(docID)` should return an object of type `PostModel`. So most likely the return type of your method should be `PostModel`. The above method was only an example. If you want to return a String, then you should change:

```
String docID = documentChange.getDocument().toObject(PostModel.class).withDocId(docID);
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, how do I define it in the POJO class? There are just setters, getters and constructors. But I have no idea how that particular addendum looks like. Sorry, I am thoroughly confused.

Comment: Then I am doing something else wrong. I already have something like that i.e. a form of a setter (edited my original question). But then Android Studio says that I should return an argument of the POJO class instead of void, which is what I am passing and also what you are suggesting.

Comment: I know my setter is fine because if I add the docId separately to an instance of the object, it is fine but I want to learn how to do it at once.

Comment: Then change the return type of your method from void to the needed type.

Comment: But then I don't know what to return since in that class I am only working with a string and there is no other return type.